# How to parse Drupal JSON data in angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, drupal, drupal-7

I got the following JSON resposne from Drupal rest api. How do I parse it in my Mobile app - AngularJs http service?

```css
[  
   {  
      "nid":"2",
      "title":"<a href=\"/sell/test-event-1\">Test Event 1</a>",
      "field_event_list":"List of Test Event 1 . List of Test Event 1 . List of Test Event 1 . List of Test Event 1 . List of Test Event 1 . List of Test Event 1 . Summery of Test Event 1 . List of Test Event 1 . List of Test Event 1 . List of Test Event 1 . List of Test Event 1 . ",
      "event_date":"<div class=\"date-display-range\"><span class=\"date-display-start\" property=\"dc:date\" datatype=\"xsd:dateTime\" content=\"2016-05-20T00:00:00+05:30\">Friday, May 20, 2016</span> to <span class=\"date-display-end\" property=\"dc:date\" datatype=\"xsd:dateTime\" content=\"2016-05-31T00:00:00+05:30\">Tuesday, May 31, 2016</span></div>"
   }
]
```

Comment: But my concern is it includes 0 <div>, p tag etc, which I already have in my mobile app. I need only data to be displayted. Is it the right way?

Comment: Use native `JSON.parse`

Comment: Did not get you! can you please give some examples? Sorry being a newbee!

Comment: @Smitha You want to get `event_date` as `Tuesday, May 31, 2016` or with `HTML`??

Comment: no HTML. I do not need HTML! So I am asking if the Drupal response is incorrect? I should ask Drupal dev to provide me correct JSON?

Comment: @Smitha Have a try with the Answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111091/discussion-between-jenson-m-john-and-smitha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eg.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MyCtrlr', function ($scope, $http) {


                      $http.get("YOUR_DRUPAL_API").success(function(response){

                         //Store your JSON Response
                                 $scope.jsonResp = [  
                                                   {  
                                                      "nid":"2",
                                                      "title":"<a href=\"/sell/test-event-1\">Test Event 1</a>",
                                                      "field_event_list":"List of Test Event 1 . List of Test Event 1 . List of Test Event 1 . List of Test Event 1 . List of Test Event 1 . List of Test Event 1 . Summery of Test Event 1 . List of Test Event 1 . List of Test Event 1 . List of Test Event 1 . List of Test Event 1 . ",
                                                      "event_date":"<div class=\"date-display-range\"><span class=\"date-display-start\" property=\"dc:date\" datatype=\"xsd:dateTime\" content=\"2016-05-20T00:00:00+05:30\">Friday, May 20, 2016</span> to <span class=\"date-display-end\" property=\"dc:date\" datatype=\"xsd:dateTime\" content=\"2016-05-31T00:00:00+05:30\">Tuesday, May 31, 2016</span></div>"
                                                   }
                                                ];

                       });

 });

//AngularJS filter to strip HTML tags from your JSON properties

app.filter('getPlaintext', function() {
    return function(text) {
      return  text ? String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '') : '';
   }
  });
```

**View**

```
<table ng-controller="MyCtrlr">
                <tr>
                  <td>nid</td>
                  <td>title</td>
                  <td>field_event_list</td>
                  <td>event_date</td>
                </tr>

                <tr ng-repeat="data in jsonResp">

                                <td>{{data.nid}}
                                </td>
                                <td>{{data.title | getPlaintext}}</td>

                                <td>{{data.field_event_list | getPlaintext}} 
                                </td>
                                <td>{{data.event_date | getPlaintext}}
                                </td>

                            </tr>

</table>
```

See **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jenson555/k9y0kk3z/)**

Comment: Thank you! How can i test the samething in my local (I have nodejs server), by using a simple json or text file?

Comment: @Smitha Haven't worked with `node.js`. Need to Check

Comment: yes. Say, I want to test $http request resposne and app logic.. but for that my server is not ready yet with REST APIs. But i have local JSON data. To test it

Comment: @Smitha See this **Fiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/jenson555/k9y0kk3z/ Here For testing, I just assigned your `JSON` to a variable. You can see `$http` AJAX call had been Commented. Similar way assign your whole `JSON` to a variable & Parse accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! That helped!